# GitHub Actions: Validation failed on adding if expression

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-cdk

I have a GitHub Actions workflow yml file which does terraform CDKTF diff, and it was working but once I added this if condition `if: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request && (github.event.comment.body == 'cdktf diff' || github.event.comment.body == 'cdktf deploy')}}`,

I am below getting error after the terraform plan output:

```
Error: Validation Failed: {"message":"The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.","resource":"Search","field":"q","code":"invalid"}
```

Below is my workflow:

```yaml
name: "Comment a CDKTF Command on a PR"

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  issue_comment:
    types: [ created ]
  
# Allows GHA to read comment and write terraform plan output on PR  
permissions:
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write  

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  cdktf_diff:
    if: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request && (github.event.comment.body == 'cdktf diff' || github.event.comment.body == 'cdktf deploy')}}
    name: "Terraform CDK Diff"
    runs-on: size/medium
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: temurin
          java-version: 17

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "16"

      - name: Generate module and provider bindings
        run: |
            cd postgres-rds-cdktf
            npx cdktf-cli get --language java
      - name: Run Terraform CDK Plan
        uses: hashicorp/terraform-cdk-action@v0.1.0
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        with:
          terraformVersion: 1.4.5
          cdktfVersion: 0.15.5
          mode: plan-only
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          workingDirectory: postgres-rds-cdktf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding below permission, the error is resolved

```
permissions:
  issues: write
```

found the answer in documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs